# SSL error in .NET Core 3 Linux app on azure

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-webapps

I've published a .NET Core 3 (preview 9) to Azure Web app running on linux. Unfortunately the app won't start and logs show this error:

`System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to configure HTTPS endpoint. No server certificate was specified, and the default developer certificate could not be found or is out of date.
2019-09-18T11:45:51.528664649Z To generate a developer certificate run 'dotnet dev-certs https'`

I'm accessing the site using the `*.azurewebsites.net` domain which should have SSL enabled by default. I've published this exact app to Windows Web app without any troubles.

I'm not familiar with Linux very much, but I would like to host it there as its cheaper and seems to offer better performance. Any ideas how can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it was a configuration issue. Once I switched to using

```
WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .UseUrls(YourUrls)
                .UseKestrel()
                .ConfigureKestrel(options =>
                {
                    options.ListenAnyIP(8080);
                })
                .UseIIS()
```

It started working under Linux just fine.

Comment: What is the functional difference with these calls in the end?

Answer (score 4):

This seems to be familiar issue, try the following

```
dotnet dev-certs https --clean
dotnet dev-certs https -t
```

Comment: hey, I've seen this before, but I don't really know where should I run this. I'm deploying with Azure Dev Ops.

Comment: you need to add a dotnet core cli task and add these commands

Comment: I tried adding that task (see edit in my post), but it doesn't seem to run. I'm using Ubuntu VM if that makes any difference.

Comment: so, this doesn't help unfortunately because `dotnet dev-certs https -t` is not supported on Linux :/

Answer (score 0):

Same problem for me with Ubuntu 18.04. Solved using the following configuration (based on Enn answer). I found that UseUrls and UseIIS are not necessary.

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            webBuilder.UseKestrel()
                .ConfigureKestrel(options =>
                {
                    options.ListenAnyIP(5000);
                });
        });
```